# How to code play stop button on android studio

Tags: android

I need some advice about the code below. I'm trying to create a simple apps that when people click play button, then the music will start playing, and when people click the stop button, the music will stop playing. I'm using a single button for this two task start and stop.

I already test on android simulator, this start and stop button are working properly as I wanted to. But the problem occurred when I build an APK file and play it on a device. The stop button cannot work as I wanted to. If I press the stop button, the music will restart the playing from the beginning.

Any ideas about this problem? Thank you.

```
btn_playstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btn_playstop.isPressed()) {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.stop();
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.seekTo(0);
                    btn_playstop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
                else {
                    player.start();
                    btn_playstop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the play/stop button, do it this way.

```
btn_playstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            player = null;
              try {
                 player.prepare();
              } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
              player.seekTo(0);  //<---- This is to resume the player from a specified position. It is helpful for a pause button. You can remove it for a stop button.
              btn_playstop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

         }
        else {              
            player.start();
                btn_playstop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
        }
     }   

});
```

You don't have to call the `seekTo(Length)` method for a stop button as it is meant for resuming the player from a specified position. Also `if (btn_playstop.isPressed())` is unnecessary as you have already called the button using `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the music still keep playing after I clicked the stop button. Everything looks normal when I run on the simulator. But once I run on the device, the music still playing.

Comment: Check the edited answer. If the problem still persists in a real device, try testing in another device.

Comment: I tried your code but the apps suddenly closed. So in the mean time, I use 'player.pause()' instead of 'player.stop()'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
imabutton=findViewById(R.id.imgbutton);
imabutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (imabutton.getTag().toString().contains("not_playing")){
            if (mediaPlayer!=null)mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music1);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            imabutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
            imabutton.setTag("playing");
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    imabutton.setTag("not_playing");
                    imabutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }
            });
        }else {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            imabutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            imabutton.setTag("not_playing");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).